# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, extjs4

I am new to Extjs. I am trying to destroy my component.

To achieve this, I am trying to pass my component name using the `getCmp` method.I am unsure how to pass the id.

This is my `component id` -

```
Ext.tab.Panel{itemId: "sportsSeenTabPanels", id:"panel-117"}
```

providing my code below

```
if (ball.Desktop.isConfigured()) {
        ball.Desktop.onMainContentDestroy(function() {
            Ext.getCmp('id').destroy();
        });
    }
```

The following is the error I receive -

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

Comment: `Ext.getCmp('id')` is returning `null`.

Comment: @JSantosh how to get the value do you know

Comment: i didn't work on Ext.Js . My assumption is there is no component with `id` in your code. I don't know know what  does `id` refers to in this context. So make sure that `id` parameter is correct.

Comment: The parameter of `Ext.getCmp` is the name you gave to the `id`. `Ext.getCmp('panel-117').destroy();`. You should use also `itemId` instead of `id` for good practices with ExtJS (https://www.sencha.com/blog/top-10-ext-js-development-practices-to-avoid-2/)

Comment: @qmat but when I try to pass  sportsSeenTabPanels its not working, do you know why

Comment: @texirv Because `getCmp` expect the `id` of the component not the `itemId`. If you want to use the `itemId` you have to use selectors in your controller.

Comment: @qmat: do you know which method accepts itemId, and I would like to destroy using that one

Comment: @texirv read the link of my previous comment and you'll find the correct way to get the component.

Comment: @qmat: i looked at the link, not sure which method are you referring too

Comment: Why do you think the tab panel will be left undestroyed? If it is a child component of the "MainContent" your `onMainContentDestroy` is referring to, then it will be destroyed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

if you make a component/panel like this :

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel',{
  title: 'panel Parent',
  id: 'parentID',
  items: [
    {
      xtype: 'panel',
      title: 'child panel',
      id: 'childID',
      itemId: 'childItemID'
    }
  ]
});
```

you can select component using :
`Ext.getCmp('childID')` or `Ext.getCmp('parentID').down('#childItemID');`

Answer (score 0):

As S Rifai suggested, you should use the relatively new EXT JS syntax for your components (introduced in the version 4,5 and 6) rather than the EXT JS 3 syntax.

Nonetheless `Ext.getCmp('myComponentId').destroy();` works. You made a typo in your code at this line :

> `Ext.getCmp('id').destroy();`

`'id'` is the name of the tag, replace it with its value : `'panel-117'`

> `Ext.getCmp('panel-117').destroy();`